# Using a CSV file to access data in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a project for my CSCI101 class at college, was thinking of using a CSV file to look at data for baseball players, like batting average, strikeout percentage, WAR, etc. to determine who should be player of the week using those numbers. Is there a way to look at data line by line in a CSV file? Like if a line of the CSV is "PlayerName, .247, .421, 22.4" and I want to save each of those numbers to a separate variable using the column headers. I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if the question doesn't really make sense. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow and python programming! There are two ways you can do this, by iterating line by line and using pandas's DataFrame lib. Try the second one first `import pandas as pd` and in a new line `df = pd.read_csv("string_path_your_file", sep=',')` and finally `print(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn it into a list which is the easiest way.

```
import csv
data=[]
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        data.append(line)
```

Now the variable data holds each line. To get the player name of the ith line, do `data[i][0]`. I hope this helps, I don't totally understand what you mean by variables using column headers. If you mean having each column feed a list, then just turn data into each list through comprehension. For example, to make the list of player names do `player_names = [line[0] for line in data]` which takes the first item in each line

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

the package [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is probably what you need here.
Specifically, the function [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) will let you create directly a dataframe (structured data structure that represents a table) storing your data.

You can then do all the analysis you need :)